# VNC Server for a Headless Debian box?

Tags: linux, debian, vnc, debian-wheezy

Which VNC Server can I use to run graphical applications (i.e. X Clients) on a headless Debian  Wheezy box?

Usually I don't need graphical applications on servers but from time to time there are applications (e.g. firmware update utilities) which sadly required a graphical interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need VNC or even to run X via a service, though X and whatever gnome-visual stuff will get installed along with your visual program. I use aptitude to install to keep an eye on the dependencies.

I use graphical apps via `ssh` from home all the time without doing anything special, just use `ssh -X` as you would `ssh` before. Once logged in, you background the task, example:
`$ midori &`
and then the window eventually appears just as if it were your local machine.

I do it mostly for getting a browser inside the network to manage something. The last time, I previously used firefox, but my new Debian install is without anything.

One tool I did really like and enjoy was opening xfce-panel on the server from my linux desktop, in which I had a few different useful plugins, including hardware monitoring. Sometimes gedit would come in handy when I knew there'd be many edits and it seemed faster to start a new shell with -X and then background the GUI rather than just use vi.

**Edit to add:** You reminded me I needed an internal browser, so from home I just installed a [bunch of browsers](https://wiki.debian.org/WebBrowsers) on my work's host & `midori` is the best I have tried yet. Netsurf couldn't open webmin, arora was way too slow, & epiphany was slower than normal to show GUI input.

Comment: BTW, just installed epiphany-browser. Wow, forgot how much gnome poop there is. I looked at the dependencies & they didn't seem like the several hundred that did install. :P + it's slow, so I'm looking at the others here: https://wiki.debian.org/WebBrowsers

Comment: Ah, of course you're right. I was too unspecific with my question. I was looking for something that keeps the applications running once I log out. I'll mark your answer anyway because it correctly answers the question as I asked it.

Comment: Ah, for those fun instances, you can evoke and then background the `nohup` command (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) but not sure how that and GUI work together based on my prior usage of remote X sessions and `nohup`s. I use `nohup` to start informal services or long `wget`s and then logout.

Answer (score 3):

The nature of X is such that you can run your display server on another machine. The easiest way to start GUI apps is login from another unix machine with `ssh -X` and then simply start the application. It will then appear on your local computer.